# How to add fluid symbol to figure

Tags: symbols, draw

I'm working on recreating the diagram below in Latex using Tikz. I have everything done except for the line under the \nabla which I circled with the red box. Any help on the name of the symbol or how to draw it would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide the code you have so far, so that others do not have to work from scratch.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the field at all, but maybe it is possible to use a different icon for "water level", especially since the icon is labeled with text? Maybe something like `$\threesim$` defined as `\newcommand*{\threesim}{\mathrel{\vcenter{\offinterlineskip\hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}\vskip-.35ex\hbox{$\sim$}}}}` (definition from http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)